# prove that $1^3+2^3+\ldots+n^3= \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ using geometrically

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

For all integers $n\geq1$ prove the following  identity using geometrically.

> $$1^3+2^3+\ldots+n^3= \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$$

I can prove the statement using mathematical induction. I want to find a geometrically proof

Thanks!

Comment: see the picture in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3938027/59379).

Comment: There are some similar questions. For example: [2598637](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2598637/sum-of-the-cubes-of-the-first-%24n%24-natural-numbers). You can try SearchOnMath too. [SearchOnMath results](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B+1%5E3%2B2%5E3%2B%5Cldots%2Bn%5E3%3D+%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bn%28n%2B1%29%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright%29%5E2+%7D%24+geometrically+proof&page=1)

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach here is to slice the cubes into layers of n(n-1), except for the last, which is n².

So you put the 1.1.1 cube, and around it two rectangles 2.1.1, and the square 2.2.1.  This makes a square whose sides are (1+2).

The 3-cube gives 3 slices of 3.3.1.  Since the side of the square is now 3, we can place these squares to double the existing square.

The 4.4.4 cube is cut into a 4.4.1 layer, and the remainder is cut 4.3.1 four times.  We can put two of these 4.3.1 so that the 3 side is against the existing square, and the 4 side enongens the edge, a pair of these will fill the inner edge, and the 4.4.1 array goes in the corner far from 1.

Repeat steps 3, 4 for odd and even numbers, as far as necessary.  The shape formed will be a square, of the sum of numbers.